# segfault on EOF while loop in c

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault, eof

We've narrowed down the issue to this function.  This one's meant to take in a a group of words to be searched for like:
    fish
    john
    miss
    nope
that appear immediately after an NxN grid to search, and extend to the end of the file.
I'm attempting to put these words into a 2D array-like structure using pointers, and she's giving me a segmentation fault.
Help?
Here's the code:

```
    int acceptItems(char** items)/*Function reads in 2D array of items to be searched for*/
{
    int row = 0;/*row, col keep track of position*/
    int col = 0;
    int numWords;/*Number of words to be searched for*/
    int end = 1;/*1 means continue, 0 means end*/
    char c;/*Temporary char for input*/

    while(end == 1)
    {
        c = getchar();

        if(c == EOF)/*Case ends repetition at end of file*/
        {
            end = 0;
        }   
        else if(c == '\n')
        {
            items[row][col] = '\0';
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            items[row][col] = c;
            col++;
        }
    }

    numWords = row + 1;

    return numWords;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc3.html might help?

Answer (score 1):

Can't be 100% sure since you haven't posted your function call, but your `items` array is probably too small. You are going out of bounds when you try to set `items[row][col]`.

Comment: Tried enlarging it, but no dice :( (Current size is good)
Any other ideas?
Here's the function call and related from main:                      

     char **items;/*Will hold words to be found*/
     
     int numWords;/*Number of words to be searched for*/

     items = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*100);

     for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
     {
         items[j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
     }

     numWords = acceptItems(items);

Comment: edit the function call into your main post. It's difficult to read code when it's all on one line like that.

Answer (score 1):

1) In `main()`, insure `items` is declared as pointer, not `int`.

```
// char items;  (from comment)
char** items;   (** may or may not be missing from your comment. @Red Alert)
```

2) Declare `ch` as `int`.  `getchar()` returns 256 different `char` *and* `EOF`.  To distinguish these 257 different results, do not use `char`, but `int`.

```
// char c;
int c;
...
c = getchar();
```

3) Upon detecting EOF, terminate the current string.  ( I think this is it. By not terminating this line, using `numWords = row + 1` and your last text line *not* ending with a `\n`, the terminator is never set when printing last line, which has no \0 leads down to the scary place of UB.)

```
if(c == EOF)/*Case ends repetition at end of file*/
  {
  items[row][col] = '\0';
  end = 0;
  }
```

4) Add test to insure you are not writing out of bounds.  The is the 2nd idea that somewhere code has boldly gone where no code has gone before.

```
if (row >= 100 || col >= 100) HandleError();
items[row][col] = ...
```

5) Suggest changing `numWords` count.

```
 numWords = row;
 if (col > 0) numWords++;
```

Comment: I think he declared `items` correctly, it's just the site formats `**` as bold if it isn't in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a 2D array outside of function `acceptItems`, and then pass it as an argument when you call this function, then you need to provide (in the function's declaration) **at least** the "lower" dimension:

```
int acceptItems(char items[][COLS])
```

You can also provide both dimensions, although you don't have to:

```
int acceptItems(char items[ROWS][COLS])
```

The general rule for any type of array, is that you have to provide all dimensions except for the "highest":

```
int func(int arr[][S2][S3][S4][S5])
```

BTW, function `getchar` returns an `int` (in order to allow the **end-of-file** indication). So you should basically use `int c` instead of `char c` (I don't think that you will ever have `c == EOF` otherwise).

Comment: This is wrong. If you use malloc correctly, there is no problem with defining a function the way OP did.

Comment: @Red Alert: Well, you're right, I should emphasize that the function needs to be declared that way **only if** the actual argument passed to the function **is** declared as an array **outside** the function (which, according to OP's description appears to be the case... nevertheless, I **should** mention that)... thanks